# call jQuery on <li> using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to call a jQuery on this element:

```
<li class="expanded nolink">
  <span>SERVICES</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first leaf">
      <a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

when hovering over SERVICES, I want ul class "menu" to show up and when i leave the `<li>`, it should disappear again. I've been trying around an am starting to get all desperate...
the url is: http://wittmerperformance.com/site/

The script I have so far looks something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var fade = $('.menu');
  $('.expanded nolink').hover(function(){
  alert("hello world!");
fade.fadeIn();
  }, function() {
fade.fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: "call a jQuery" is not a very meaningful request.

Comment: can you show your script

Comment: Why did you link a site _no one has access to_?

Comment: @Daedalus if you cancel the prompt, it still loads (which brings up a separate question...)

Comment: @Sara Thanks.. and a separate question indeed c.c

Comment: @Sibu, I added the script i had to my post above...

Comment: @Daedalus I now uncommented .htaccess on my ftp - no more prompt

Comment: @cerr Not quite the point; your .htaccess doesn't work anyway.

Comment: he added script and fixed link , id take away downvotes if that what they were for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, you should change:

```
$('.expanded nolink')
```

to:

```
$('.expanded.nolink')
```

You can also use `fadeToggle` method:

```
$(function(){
   $('.menu').hide();
   $('li.expanded').hover(function(){
      $('.menu', this).fadeToggle()
   })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

#### There is an error in your jQuery code, the selector is wrong:

Change `$('.expanded nolink')` to `$('.expanded.nolink')`, as the selector is not selecting anything, your code might not work!

You have this code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="expanded nolink">
        <span>SERVICES</span>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first leaf">
                <a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf">
                <a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf">
                <a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Pure CSS Solution

```
​ul li.expanded ul {display: none;}
ul li.expanded:hover ul {display: block;}​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhhQz/

#### jQuery Solution

```
$(document)​.ready(function(){
    $("ul li.expanded ul").hide();
    $("ul li.expanded").hover(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").stop().fadeIn(400);
    }, function(){
        $(this).children("ul").stop().fadeOut(400);
    });
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhhQz/1/

Comment: You can use either Pure CSS or jQuery method. Any one! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically using `hover`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li.expanded").hover(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).children("ul").hide();
    });
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CU83B/​

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="expanded nolink">
  <span >SERVICES</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first leaf">
      <a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

$(function() {
  var fade = $('.menu');
  $('.expanded').hover(function(){
  fade.fadeIn();
  }, function() {
fade.fadeOut();
  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wAch8/1/)

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wAch8/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to give an ID for that LI first, calling with the class is a bit loosely coupled

```
<li id="my-id" class="expanded nolink"><span>SERVICES</span><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a></li>

    $("#my-id").hover(
    function(){
      //Show the span
    },

    function(){
    //Hide the span
    }
    );
```